# Google maps aviso: getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estou usando o laravel com um virtualhost e preciso fazer com que o mapa funcione no localhost, só que já tenho a chave do google e mesmo assim, sem colocar as devidas restrições na chave ainda aparece a mensagem. Como que eu faço para o Mapa trabalhar no ambiente localhost?
Segue o código da localização que mostra a mensagem:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent('Esta é a sua localização.');
    map.setCenter(pos);
}, function () {
    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
});
} else {
    // Browser não suporta localização
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}
```

Comment: você liberou a url localhost no console api do google?

Comment: Como que faz isso?

Comment: Acessa https://console.developers.google.com, dentro da guia Credenciais você clica na credencial gerada e adiciona localhost como URL confiável para teste!

Comment: Mas lá só tem opções de restrições de chaves

Answer (score 1):

Já passei por esse problema em alguns testes que fiz e precisei alterar pra acessar a tela (o site todo, na verdade) via `https`.

referência: https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps/issues/15

Comment: Mas não tem como trabalhar no localhost? Estou usando um virtualhost como: loja.teste.com. Então vou ter que jogar o sistema online e registrar um certificado?

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca Você pode criar um self-signed certificate e usar localmente na sua máquina.